# Client/Server jars - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, client-server

I have a javafx project in eclipse ready to run. I have a client and a server.
I have tried to run server and client in eclipse and everything works fine, but when I exported to runnable jars, one to server and one to client, the server jar works fine, but the client throws exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

although it works fine before exporting in eclipse. 
Server and Client are both javafx applications that start with GUI.

ClientLauncher.java:

```
package client;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClientLauncher extends Application {

    public GCMClient gcmClient;

    private String host = "localhost";
    private int port = 5555;

    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage PrimaryStage) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Client Connection Established");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sources/ServerLogin.fxml"));
        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                PrimaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                PrimaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        PrimaryStage.setScene(scene);
        PrimaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

The exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at client.ClientLauncher.start(ClientLauncher.java:33)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Edit your question, and show us line 33 of ClientLauncher.java.  Even better would be lines 23–33 of ClientLauncher.java, so we can see how you create the location you’re passing to FXMLLoader.load.

Comment: added ClientLauncher.java  @VGR

Comment: Does your client jar contain a ServerLogin.fxml entry?  Is the entry located at `sources/ServerLogin.fxml` inside the jar?

Comment: yes it should contain, the way I created the jars is I clicked export and then jar and choose the main class. the client's main class is ClientLauncher which loads sources/ServerLogin.fxml

Comment: Did you examine the contents of your client jar and verify it?

Comment: @VGR I have solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I have misspelled ServerLogin.fxml in

```
 Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sources/ServerLogin.fxml"));
```

Which is named "ServerLogIn.fxml" in my case.

It appears that the name of the fxml is case sensitive in runnable jar, but It's not in eclipse. That's why it worked fine in eclipse and didn't work in jar.